# Azure Devops Tasks not showing up in my Task Template List

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When I create tasks for my stories using the templates section in project, the newly created tasks do not show up in my task template list. Is there somewhere in Azure Dev Ops I need to use to grant access to my teams?

Comment: Do you mean the work item template you captured doesn't show when you want to apply it? Could you show you detailed steps? Have you saved the template? Please follow this documentation to use the template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Answer (score 1):

> **Prerequisites**:
>
> - To add, capture, edit, or delete work item templates through the web    portal, you must be a member of the team under which you add
>   them.
> - To apply a work item template, you must be a Contributor of the    project and a member of the team under which the work item template
>   is defined.

Also, when you check the template list, make sure you select the correct team:

[image]